# how to install new version of a software via yum when yum repo is not updated

Tags: yum

I want to install collectd version 5.2 or above.
when I do yum install collectd, it installs 4.10 version
but on this version, my software does not work.
please help

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: It is CentOS...

Comment: Which version? 6.x?

Comment: lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Final

Comment: Ok,as mentioned earlier collectd version 5.x is not present in the official  and unofficial repositories for centos 6. If you can switch to Centos 7 there is, in the repository EPEL, the requested version, otherwise you can try to rebuild the 5.X following these instructions (i have not tried this solution): https://gist.github.com/tnolet/7361441

Comment: Thanks a lot Lilox...it worked :)
Could you also please help me how I can add an extra plugin here...?

Comment: Sure, I can try :) which plugin?

Comment: aggregation plugin...
It is used to show aggregated CPUusage

Comment: I think, by taking a quick look at the code, that the plugin is already included in the sources that you have compiled, so you just have to enable it in the configuration.

Comment: Worked fine....great You are @LilloX :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the rpm location you can directly install it via yum without downloading it.

For eg:

```
 yum install http://something.com/package1.rpm
```

Comment: It is not that simple. the answer given does not take into account the possible dependencies that still would not be satisfied.If the official repositories does not have the required version  probably are missing dependencies too.

Comment: @LilloX. Agreed. I think this will take care if a package cannot be installed just because the version in the repo is missing and it meets all the other dependencies.

Comment: tried below  
yum install ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/collectd-5.2.0-1.fc18.x86_64.rpm

But got the below message 

--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: collectd-5.2.0-1.fc18.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: collectd-5.2.0-1.fc18.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: collectd-5.2.0-1.fc18.x86_64

Packages skipped because of dependency problems